# Power Automate Flow - Strip Values

Tags: power-automate

I have the below flow:

How can I strip this down to my desired results?

The flow returns `Total_Request [{"Total_Request":100}]`

I would like to return `Total Request 100`

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the EXACT response with a screenshot? It’s unclear to me where that response is coming from. You need to zero in on it within the context of your flow so we can give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current setup outputs I would suggest to replace the **value** dynamic property in the Map field of the Select action by an expression:

```
item()?['Total_Request']
```

And you can also rename your key from Total_Request to Total Request, if you want to change the column name.